# Should I implement null object pattern in my derived event args class (i.e. EventArgs.Empty)? If so - what's the best way?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, event-handling

System.EventArgs implements a variant of the null object pattern - developers use EventArgs.Empty instead of null to designate a "nothing interesting here" situation, presumably in order to relieve the consumers of having to deal with possible null reference exceptions

I am declaring my own event with a derived event args class, say `ContosoEventArgs`
I think it would be only natural for consumers to be able to pass something like `ContosoEventArgs.Empty` (just `EventArgs.Empty` won't work as this would be an attempt to assign an instance of a base class to a variable of the derived class), as they are used to. 
This, however, is tricky to implement - the Empty static property doesn't rely on some protected property IsEmpty that I can set in my derived class. If it did, I could do something like:

```
public class ContosoEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public static ContosoEventArgs Empty
    {
        get
        {
            return new ContosoEventArgs{IsEmpty=true};
        }
    }
}
```

Nice and clean!

However, such a property does not exist and to the best of my knowledge the only way to test EventArgs instance for Empty-ness is to compare to EventArgs.Empty. This means that I now need to implement operator == overload... and operator !=, and Equals(...), and GetHashCode()... all that boilerplate just to have my specialized event args follow the pattern from the base EventArgs

Should I instead just allow nulls?
I think that's pretty much what they have done in the framework itself - MouseEventArgs and ImageClickEventArgs don't show traces of null object pattern implementation

Or am I overlooking some third option?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use this code without overloading equality members:

```
public class ContosoEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public new static readonly ContosoEventArgs Empty = new ContosoEventArgs();
}
```

If you look at the EventArgs, it uses the static instance to compare:

```
 [ComVisible(true)]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
[Serializable]
public class EventArgs
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static readonly EventArgs Empty = new EventArgs();

    static EventArgs()
    {
    }
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    public EventArgs()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this makes good sense. I ended up implementing it in a another way which I like - but it's not as general, it only works for the specific situation. I'll post it shortly, as soon as I get my hands on the code